# Custom csv output name with variable in loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a code like this to process all files in folder and I've got a problem with last line.
I want to save file after each iteration with custom name.
Expample:

File in folder = SX.txt

Input value = 2

New file name = SX_2.txt

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
    
txtfiles = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    txtfiles.append(file)
print(txtfiles)

name_5=input("Mode number to extract:")

        
for filepath in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        #data1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 5))) 
        data1 = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True , index_col=None, header=None)
        data1.columns  = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e"]

        data1['mode'] = data1.groupby(['b']).ngroup()
        data1['mode_1'] = data1['mode']+1
        data_d = data1[data1['mode_1'] == float(name_5)]
        del data_d["mode"]
        data_d["b"]=data_d["b"].round(decimals=3)
        data_d["c"]=data_d["c"].round(decimals=3)

        print(data_d)

        data_d.to_csv(f'{file} + "_" + {name_5}.csv', sep=' ', index=False)
```

Last line gives an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<_io.TextIOWrapper name=\'SX1.txt\' mode=\'r\' encoding=\'cp1252\'> + "_" + 2.csv'
```

Could you help please?
Thanks

Comment: and what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

```
data_d.to_csv(f'{file} + "_" + {name_5}.csv', sep=' ', index=False)
```

- You have confused what `file` is, that is a file descriptor openned on the original file,
- you use a `+` in a `f-string`, that would string like `'SX  + "_" +  5.csv'`
- if you want to keep extension, don't write `.csv`

---

#### Fix

```
data_d.to_csv(f'{filename[:-4]}_{name_5}.txt', sep=' ', index=False)
```

---

To simplify your comprehension : use file descriptor for both read and write OR none (pandas handles filename string)

```
txtfiles = glob.glob("*.txt")
print(txtfiles)
name_5 = input("Mode number to extract:")
for filename in txtfiles:
    data1 = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=None, header=None)
    data1.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    data_d = data1[data1['mode_1'] == float(name_5)]
    # ...
    data_d.to_csv(f'{filename[:-4]}_{name_5}.csv', sep=' ', index=False)
```

Comment: Great, thank a lot!!! Now it's working! :)